# Docker MongoDB can't access from outside VM

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, spring-boot

I am new to docker and I was following a tutorial to combine microservices (written using Spring boot) and docker: http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/building-a-microservice-architecture-with-spring-boot-and-docker-part-iii.

My app (server NOT running as a docker container) is able to store data in the mongodb (running as a docker container). When I do requests to my app (rest) using postman I should get a json as return value but that does not happen (I do get a status code '200'), the same thing for every MongoDB UI out there:

[image: empty database]

When I open a shell in the MongoDB container and query my database it shows that I have data in my collection:

[image: data in db]

Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong or how I can allow access from my host environment?

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to implement getter and setter methods for my pojo object. I now get a correct response back in postman.

[image: postman post request]

One problem left, I still can't view the data in robomongo (MongoDB UI)

docker ps:

[image: docker ps -a]

Comment: what is the value of `spring.data.mongodb.uri`? what about `docker ps -a`?

Comment: mongodb://192.168.99.100:32770/micros

Comment: robomongo does not support mongo 3

Comment: I am now using 'mongochef' and I can now view my data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was using Robomongo which does not support higher MongoDB versions. I am now using mongochef which works just fine.